# Можно ли связать базу данных Filemaker с Superset Apache, чтобы я мог строить графики?

Tags: база-данных, odbc

У меня есть база данных FileMaker и суперсет apache, как мне связать базу данных FileMaker с суперсетом apache, чтобы я мог строить графики в реальном времени?

Comment: Уважаемый Denis640Kb и те, кто утвердил правку - ввиду того, что имели место быть случаи жалоб авторов, что их текст некорректно перевели их технический красивый текст на русский язык, - то было принято решение - закрывать такие вопросы с причиной - следует задавать вопрос на русском. А во вторых - если автор не владеет русским - то то что вы исправили - ему не будет понятно, и ответ врядли будет полезен.

Comment: @nick_n_a понял, хорошо. Спасибо за уточнение.

Comment: @nick_n_a Прошу прощения за невнимательность, я перепутал русский форум с английским и написал сюда по английски. Предложенная правка меня полностью устраивает и перевод сделан очень точно. Мой вопрос был передан верно.

Comment: @Denis640Kb большое спасибо за правку.